# Using sf objects properly:

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sf

I am attempting to join some data in R, I want to add census information about boroughs, blocks, etc... to longlat coordinates that I have. My data looks like the following:

```
census_data <- blocks <- tigris::blocks("NY", "Kings", 2010) #manhattan data
long_lat <- raw_data %>% select(pickup_longitude, pickup_latitude)
```

long_lat is a dataframe and:

```
head(long_lat)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  pickup_latitude pickup_longitude
            <dbl>            <dbl>
1            40.8            -74.0
2            40.7            -74.0
3            40.8            -74.0
4            40.7            -74.0
5            40.7            -74.0
6            40.8            -74.0
```

```
class(blocks)
[1] "sf"         "data.frame"

head(blocks)
Simple feature collection with 6 features and 17 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -73.98255 ymin: 40.58305 xmax: -73.92447 ymax: 40.62601
epsg (SRID):    4269
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs
```

I convert my long_lat data to be joinable with my blocks data like so:

```
long_lat_st <- st_as_sf(long_lat, coords = c("pickup_longitude",
                                         "pickup_latitude"),
                      crs = st_crs(blocks))
```

For the crs argument I am simply passing it to match the blocks data. I had tried manually encoding it as: "+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83" but when I would do that, I would end up with mismatching crs despite my specifications.

After running this function I have the following:

```
head(long_lat_st)
Simple feature collection with 6 features and 0 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -74.01006 ymin: 40.72139 xmax: -73.96774 ymax: 40.77356
epsg (SRID):    4269
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs
                    geometry
1 POINT (-73.97399 40.75726)
2 POINT (-74.01006 40.72139)
3 POINT (-73.97784 40.77356)
4  POINT (-73.9964 40.73223)
5  POINT (-73.9786 40.72432)
6 POINT (-73.96774 40.76598)
```

The proj4strings now match.

**Is it OK to pass the crs argument the way that I did or does it invalidate my longlat pairings?**

From here I am able to join my data like so without getting an error:

```
joined <- st_join(long_lat_st, blocks, left = FALSE)
```

I think that this worked correctly but I just want to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

You're applying a coordinate reference system/[datum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Datum) (description of the shape of the Earth) that is optimised for North America; if your pick-up data is from North America, and I cannot conceive of an application where it would not be, then that's all you have to do.

What you may want to check is whether you need an `inner_join` which is what your specification of `left = FALSE` selects, and whether `st_intersects` is the kind of `st_join` you are interested in.

`st_intersects` is very broadly defined, so it works well in many cases, but you may be more interested in `st_within` or others. Check out the help section with `?st_join`.

Also, check out [this online book](https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/spatial-class.html) for answers to some common geocomputation problems using `sf`.

Comment: Great, thanks. I tried adding calling: joined <- st_join(long_lat_st, blocks, join = st_within, left = FALSE) and the output object had the same dimensions as when I just used regular st_join so I'm not sure if it made a difference.